# Store and read KeyPair with Android SharedPreferences

Tags: android, serialization, preferences

I'm looking for a kind of Serialization for the [java.security.KeyPair](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/security/KeyPair.html) to store and read from the Shared Preferences.
Storing the .toString() is now quite sinful cause there is no Constructor for the KeyPair.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually solved in it this way:

I first create a String by using Base64, which I store and then recreate from the Shared Proferences:

```
    SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
                PATH, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String key = prefs.getString(KEYPATH, "");

    if (key.equals("")) {
        // generate KeyPair
        KeyPair kp = Encrypter.generateKeyPair();
        ByteArrayOutputStream b = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream o;
        try {
            o = new ObjectOutputStream(b);
            o.writeObject(kp);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        byte[] res = b.toByteArray();
        String encodedKey = Base64.encodeToString(res, Base64.DEFAULT);

        prefs.edit().putString(KEYPATH, encodedKey).commit();

    } else {
        // read the KeyPair from internal storage
        byte[] res = Base64.decode(key, Base64.DEFAULT);
        ByteArrayInputStream bi = new ByteArrayInputStream(res);
        ObjectInputStream oi;
        try {
            oi = new ObjectInputStream(bi);
            Object obj = oi.readObject();
            Encrypter.setMyKeyPair((KeyPair) obj);
            Log.w(TAG, ((KeyPair) obj).toString());
        } catch (StreamCorruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there is no way of storing a Serializable object in SharedPreferences. I recommend looking into saving it as a private file, see [Android Storage Options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal), [FileOutputStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileOutputStream.html) and [ObjectOutputStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) for more information.

```
public static void write(Context context, Object obj, String filename) {
    ObjectOutputStream oos = null;

    try {
        FileOutputStream file = context.openFileOutput(filename, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(file);
        oos.writeObject(obj);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (oos != null) {
            try {
                oos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

public static Object read(Context context, String filename) {
    ObjectInputStream ois = null;
    Object obj = null;

    try {
        FileInputStream file = context.getApplicationContext().openFileInput(filename);
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(file);
        obj = ois.readObject();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
       // Just let it return null.
       e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (ois != null) {
            try {
                ois.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    return obj;
}
```